# Characters like Ã not displaying correctly from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, character-encoding, collation

I have a problem when displaying results from a database in an HTML file in two computers.

So, in one computer it shows a name like this:

```
SAUL FRANCISCO GARCÃA RODRÃGUEZ
```

The collation of the database is `latin1_swedish_ci` and the collation of the tables is `utf8_general_ci`.

In the other computer it shows like this (I want it to be this way):

```
SAUL FRANCISCO GARCÍA RODRÍGUEZ
```

The names get listed in a `<select>` tag The language of the two browsers is English and the Html file is the same on both environments so I think It has to do with the charset or encoding for the php.ini file

I have tried changing the values in `php.ini` but nothing changes and I can't find the answer anywhere.

The only difference is that where the results get displayed as I want I installed WAMP and in the other computer I installed Apache, MySQL and PHP separately.

Sorry if the details are not very informative but I have no clue where I'm going wrong.

P.S. On both databases the data looks like this from the MySQL console:

```
SAUL FRANCISCO GARCÃA RODRÃGUEZ
```

Comment: Your problem is when are showing data in a web page?

Comment: What is the collation of the actual column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Editing `php.ini` won’t help you much in a case like this.

What is the data collation of the database giving you an issue?  By default, most MySQL installs set `latin1_swedish_ci` instead of `utf8_general_ci` for newly created databases.

Change the collation of the database & try again.

```
ALTER DATABASE [name of your database] CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

If this is a specific table, the collation can be changed as so:

```
ALTER TABLE [name of your table] CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

And if it is a specific column in a table:

```
ALTER TABLE [name of your table] MODIFY [name of your column] [other settings] CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Or perhaps you could export the current database, create a new database with this command & reimport the data:

```
CREATE DATABASE [name of your database] CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

And if you want to make a permanent change to the MySQL install on the machine giving you an issue, go and edit `my.cnf`.  The following would set the whole chain to UTF-8:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

Comment: JakeGould - Altering the database worked, editing the my.ini file worked for the subsequent databases. Didn't had to change the charset of the tables. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for your tipp. Is it possible to apply the my.cnf settings to a specific database?

Answer (score 2):

add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` to the head of your html

Answer (score 2):

You could set PHP to output the content as UTF-8:

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

In your HTML document you can specify to the browsers that the content it is UTF-8, by putting this in the HEAD of your pages:

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`