# Arabic data transfer between multiple tables in different MySQL databases returning ???????? as new values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I inserted some data from a `letters` field in `database1.table1` to `new_letters` field in `database2.table2` by using PHP, but all the values are changed to question marks like `????? ?????? ????? ??????? ?? ??? ???? ????? ?????` in the `new_letters` field. Structure of the `letters` is (Type:longtext, Collation: utf8_general_ci), and the structure of the `new_letters` is (Type:mediumtext, Collation: utf8_unicode_ci). Also, I need to mention that even changing both collations to utf8_unicode_ci or utf8_general_ci did not solve the problem. Could you please let me know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your entire chain from the connection, to the database, to the tables is all UTF8 clean.  I have a detailed answer to [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624445/characters-like-not-displaying-correctly-from-mysql/20624493#20624493).

But in your case, check the actual MySQL server `my.cnf` file. The following would set the whole chain to UTF-8:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I applied your settings to `my.cnf` file, but still there is no change, is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I also added this to the top of my PHP file `mysqli_query($dbcon, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");` in addition to your settings in `my.conf` and now is working fine,

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure your collation and character sets are consistent. For instance, you have two different collations (`utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_unicode_ci`), so you should convert them both to the same collation. I believe UTF-8 supports Arabic letters.

So, CHARACTER SET utf8 and COLLATE utf8_general_ci

Comment: I changed both fields to `utf8_general_ci` but there was no change, still all the same problem

Comment: Do I need to apply specific condition before the query execution?

Comment: @Apiah: you also need to make sure your php<->mysql connection is set for utf8 as well. ALL stages of the entire process have to set for utf8, or you'll get mangled text.