# How to properly output unicode characters in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

Hello forgive me for being new to this but I'm trying to output some unicode data from my php file.

The string that is suppose to be output is: "**SD Tết Festival**"

However I seem to be getting: "SD T\u1ebft Festival"

It's probably an easy overlook, but I cant figure it out.

I have searched and followed solutions here:

1. [How to take unicode characters from the mysql data base in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584558/how-to-take-unicode-characters-from-the-mysql-data-base-in-php)
2. [How to display Unicode data with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446778/how-to-display-unicode-data-with-php)

PHP snippet code:

```
$sql = "select * from info";

mysqli_query($connection, "set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysqli_query($connection, "set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysqli_query($connection, "set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

$rowCount = $result->num_rows;
$index = 1  ;
$newArray = [];
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    $newArray[$row['type']] = $row['content'];    
}

echo json_encode($newArray);
```

What do I seem to be doing wrong?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I've added the following code as suggested by the solution in the duplicate question:

```
$connection->set_charset('utf8mb4');
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8mb4');
```

and removed:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysqli_query($connection, "set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysqli_query($connection, "set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
```

However, the output is still the same.

**UPDATE 2:**
As suggested in the comment, I made sure the table and collation supports utf8mb4 as so:

[image]

[image]

I still seem to be getting the same output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: would appreciate the comment on my update..thanks

Comment: The collation of the tables and field also have to be utf8mb4. Check if the data inside the table are not corrupt.

Comment: MySQL never generates `\u1ebf`; something else is generating that Unicode string.  (And for that reason, I doubt if this is a dup of what Charlotte suggests.)

Comment: Please do `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` just to determine whether the Unicode code was generated _before_ inserting, or during _ouput_.

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong. `"SD T\u1ebft Festival"` is a valid way of encoding that string in JSON. A JSON parser (eg. `JSON.parse` in javascript) will turn that back into `SD Tết Festival`.