# PDO cutting off strings at a UTF-8 character

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP 5.5 and when I attempt to insert a UTF-8 character in the MySQL database PDO cuts it off at the first non-ASCII character.

I have set my connection to be:

```
(DB_TYPE.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING))
```

I have tried the SET NAMES that everyone posts, but that doesn’t work either because the problem is NOT on the MySQL side of things.

When I do an insert through phpMyAdmin and directly from the MySQL console, it works!
When I select the accented string with PDO, it works!

The problem is only on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` using PDO specifically!

Here is the SQL of the table. It is all in UTF-8 but maybe someone knows of a conflict between a setting and PDO

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_lang` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `id_tgroup_cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fieldfor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `colors` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=34 ;
```

I have already tried to make text a varchar field and that did not change anything.

The actual insert in PHP:

```
    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE mytable
                                    SET text = ?,
                                        colors = ?
                                    WHERE id = ?");
    $query->execute(array($text, $colors, $id));
```

Where `$text = "référence"` (only saves the letter R in the database but without accents it saves everything) and $colors is an empty string for test purposes and `$id` is `2`.

Comment: `var_dump($text)` yields `string(11) "référence"`?

Comment: Yes it does yeild that.

Comment: Tried solutions in that question too @MarcusAdams - no success. Jake might be on to something though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the key clue to me:

> Where $text = "référence" (only saves the letter R in the database but
>   without accents it saves everything) and $colors is an empty string
>   for test purposes and $id is 2.

Sounds like it is a UTF-8 encoding issue. While the database is UTF-8 the whole chain from the code to the database—including the connection—should be UTF-8 clean.

How exactly does `$this->db->prepare` relate to the PHP connection to MySQL? A bit unclear from the code you have shown. But based on what you are showing, perhaps adjusting your query like this would help:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("SET collation_connection = utf8_bin;
                             SET NAMES utf8;
                             UPDATE mytable
                                SET text = ?,
                                    colors = ?
                                WHERE id = ?");
```

Or maybe this:

```
$this->db->exec("SET collation_connection = utf8_bin; SET NAMES utf8;");
$query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE mytable
                                SET text = ?,
                                    colors = ?
                                WHERE id = ?");
```

Note my forced-in addition of `SET collation_connection = utf8_bin;` as well as `SET NAMES utf8;`

In general you need to make sure your entire chain from the connection, to the database, to the tables is all UTF8 clean.  I have a detailed answer to [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624445/characters-like-not-displaying-correctly-from-mysql/20624493#20624493).

But in your case, check the actual MySQL server `my.cnf` file. The following would set the whole chain to UTF-8:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

**EDIT:** And since the original poster indicates the data is coming from an HTML5 form, I also think checking the BOM (byte order mark) for the actual HTML5 file itself would help as well. It should be set to UTF8. More details on [what a BOM is are over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom). Specifically the accepted answer from Martin Code which explains:

> The UTF-8 BOM is a sequence of bytes (EF BB BF) that allows the reader
>   to identify the file as an UTF-8 file.

Comment: As stated in the OP, that doesn't work (and there are better ways to do this through PDO) - it obviously is a utf8 mismatch - I just need to figure out where and why :)

Comment: Hi, yes they come from an HTML5 form with charset specified as the first meta tag. - gonna go check the config files and your other answer now.

Comment: Maybe there is something there, it is in ascii, not utf-8.

Comment: After looking for BOM, there is none.

Comment: Ok got it to work by deleting and recreating the file as utf8

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 12.04. It still has no BOM, but now it saves so its all that matters. I was working from a copied file though, so perhaps there was something set wrong with it to start with.