# Using Chinese characters in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use Chinese characters in mysql table. On my first try I wrote something like 中文考试 and my table came back with `è¿˜æœ‰ä¸€ä¸ªè€ƒè¯•`.

After research, it was suggested that I use the UTF-8 as my character set. I went back to my table and altered the character set with the command

```
ALTER TABLE posts CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

I tried writing Chinese characters again and got the same result - (  `è¿˜æœ‰ä¸€ä¸ªè€ƒè¯•`.).

Here is a copy of my table as it exist right now:

[image]

How can I get my table to accept Chinese characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After research, it was suggested that I use the UTF-8 as my character
>   set.

You need to make sure your entire chain from the connection, to the database, to the tables is all UTF8 clean.  I have a detailed answer to [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624445/characters-like-not-displaying-correctly-from-mysql/20624493#20624493).

But in your case, check the actual MySQL server `my.cnf` file. The following would set the whole chain to UTF-8:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

The `my.cnf` is the main MySQL configuration file. Depending on your OS it can be located in a few places. For example in Ubuntu 12.04 it can be found here:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

So figure out where yours is located, open up that file, edit it, restart MySQL & you should be good to go.